# Filling an array with values which sum to $1$ and look like gaussian

Tags: statistics

I need a formula which will fill an array of X slots with values (from $0$ to $1$). The sum of all array values should be $1$. The values should look like this:

```
^
|
|
|
0.2
|
|
|         .....
|      ..       ..
|    .             .
|  .                 .
| .                   .
|.                     .
|.                     .
+------------------------array-slot->
```

Which means that for an array of size 7 I'd approximatelly want something like:

```
i[0]=0.09
i[1]=0.14
i[2]=0.17
i[3]=0.20 
i[4]=0.17
i[5]=0.14
i[6]=0.09
```

which add to exactly $1$ and look like gaussian (or something).

Accuracy is not very important but I'd like it to sum to $1$ and not look linear.

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used a good old sine implementation for this which solved my problem.

```
public static double[] getProbabilities(int size) {
    double[] result = new double[size];
    double sum = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        result[i] = Math.sin((i+1)/((double)size+1) * Math.PI);
        sum+=result[i];
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        result[i] /= sum;
    }
    return result;
}
```

The first loop assigns values and also calculates the sum. The second loop normalizes all values so the end sum is 1.

For size 7 it produces:

```
0.07612046748871325
0.140652283836026
0.18377106498543178
0.198912367379658
0.18377106498543178
0.140652283836026
0.07612046748871326
```

Which is symetrical, adds up to 1 and looks like the graph I mentioned in my question.

Answer (score 3):

Just use the [binomial probability density](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_distribution) for $p=1/2$ and $n$ equal to the size of your array minus 1.

Comment: Could you just show me a formula which will do that? I'm not a mathematician.

Comment: The formula is on the page I linked to.

Comment: Doesn't really help me since my maths knowledge is not in good shape. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 1):

Let's f(x) = a . exp((x-b)²/(2.c²)) with :
 - a having any value (explained later)
 - b = (n-1)/2
 - c having any value (proportional to n would make sense though)

Then :
    int sum=0;
    for (int i=0; i smaller than n; i++)
    {
      a[i] = f(i);
      sum+=a[i];
    }
    for (int i=0; i smaller than n; i++)
    {
      a[i]/=sum;
    }

I haven't tried but it seems to make sense. Maybe there'll be a problem of offset but you'll see it when testing.

Comment: Thanks. I used the sum and divide to normalize the values.